# "Cheers to a new year" is idiom or literal?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

On New year greetings card we get to see:

> Cheers to a new year.

Is it idiomatic or literal?

I am familiar with :

> Cheer --Noun and verb.

I have heard about:

> Cheer for someone

Online dictionaries didn't help me.

Comment: I don't think native speakers of English generally say or write "Cheers to new year."

Comment: You need to search for "cheers" not "cheer"

Comment: "Cheers to the freaking weekend, I'll drink to that" - Rihanna

Answer (score 1):

[**cheers**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheers) is an interjection commonly used as a toast. It is often followed by “to X” to indicate who or what is being toasted: “Cheers to you”, “Cheers to your promotion”, “Cheers to a happy new year”.